# Node.js process continues to write to old log file

Tags: javascript, node.js, logging, winston

I am having some trouble setting up log rotation for my node.js server. It seems that the process continues to write to the old file. My log rotation config is as follows:

```
/var/log/node.js.log {
  daily
  rotate 1
  maxsize 20M
  su root root
  create 0700 root root
  missingok
  compress
  sharedscripts
}
```

When the logrotation script runs, the new log stays at 0 bytes, and by running `lsof | grep deleted` I can see that the old log file continues to grow, eventually filling up all the disk on the machine. Do I really have to restart the node.js process every time I rotate the log?

Answer (score 0):

The currently written file can be reused with the `copytruncate` option in logrotate.